# Can't get my component to conditionally render out

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering

I have a few different const functions I would like to return and render.  I have it set to always render out the Main menu unless a button is pressed, which updates my state to the name of the button.  Each button name has another set of buttons that it should render out (exactly like main menu), but I can't get them to render out.

My current code renders the main menu and when a button is selected instead of rendering out a new line of buttons, it renders out just the name of the button selected.  I would like my conditional to render out the state name component if possible.

this.state.selected is only rendering out a String.  I would like to incase it in maybe...

```
<this.state.selected />
```

However, this doesn't work.

```
return (
            <div>
                {this.state.selected === '' ? <MainMenu /> : this.state.selected }
            </div>
        )
```

EDIT -  Adding all of the code for more information

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchBar from 'material-ui-search-bar'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'

class OverviewRender extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             selected: ''
         }
       }

    handleClick(name) {
        this.setState({
            selected: name
        });
        console.log("testing" + this.state.selected);
    }

    render() {
        const MainMenu = () => (
            <div>
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="File Options"
                    onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'FileOptions')}
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="Setup Options"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="More Options"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="Shift Setup"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                /> <br />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="View/Report"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="Troubleshooting"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );

        const FileOptions = () => (
            <div>
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="Load Values"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
                <RaisedButton 
                    label="Open Values From Disk"
                    style={{
                        height: '80px',
                        width: '180px',
                        fontSize: '44px',
                        padding: '1px'
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );

        const { Selected } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                {Selected === '' ? <MainMenu /> : <Selected />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class Overview extends Component {
    constructor(props){
            super(props)
                this.state = {
                    open: false
                }
            }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="menuButtons">
                <br />
                <OverviewRender />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Overview;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way if you could do this in your code

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = { Selected: null }
  }
  render () {
    const { Selected } = this.state
    return (
        <div>
           {Selected === '' ? <MainMenu /> : <Selected /> }
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

you must know that React will only render if follow its convention name. See again above

edit to reflect updated question above

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import SearchBar from 'material-ui-search-bar'
import sass from '../scss/application.scss'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton'

const FileOptions = () => (
     <div>
        <RaisedButton label="Load Values" style={{ height: '80px', width: '180px', fontSize: '44px', padding: '1px'}} />
        <RaisedButton label="Open Values From Disk" style={{ height: '80px', width: '180px', fontSize: '44px', padding: '1px'}} />
     </div>
);

class OverviewRender extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = { 
             Selected: null
         }
       }

    handleClick(name) {
        this.setState({
            Selected: name
        });
        console.log("testing" + this.state.Selected);
    }

    MainMenu = () => (
      <div>
         <RaisedButton label="File Options" onClick={() => this.setState({ Selected: FileOptions })} style={{ height: '80px', width: '180px', fontSize: '44px', padding: '1px' }} />
         <RaisedButton label="Setup Options" style={{ height: '80px', width: '180px', fontSize: '44px', padding: '1px'}} />
         <RaisedButton label="More Options" style={{height: '80px',width: '180px',fontSize: '44px',padding: '1px'}} />
         <RaisedButton label="Shift Setup" style={{height: '80px',width: '180px',fontSize: '44px',padding: '1px'}} />
         <br />
         <RaisedButton label="View/Report" style={{ height: '80px', width: '180px', fontSize: '44px', padding: '1px' }} />
         <RaisedButton label="Troubleshooting" style={{ height: '80px', width: '180px', fontSize: '44px', padding: '1px'}} />
      </div>
    )

    render() {    
        const { Selected } = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
               {this.MainMenu()} 
               {Selected === '' ? <MainMenu /> : <Selected />}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

check again its initial state.

Comment: I didn't minus one you, but that doesn't quite work.

Comment: what do you mean? how the expected output?

Comment: It just doesn't work.  Specifically changing the check to 'Selected ==='.  This breaks the code

Comment: did you notice the big caps of `Selected`? What is initial value of this state?

Comment: did you put it in `render()` function? and update the name of the state in constructor?

Comment: I think that's what I have above.  It breaks with an undefined error when compiling / running.

Comment: Not sure where to look - it looks the same but with the edition of adding NULL to Selected state

Comment: not the same. Check the `constructor` and spelling of `Selected`

Comment: Still not working.  I think maybe it has something to do with onClick()  does this function properly update the state?

Comment: still nothing  -  I think it might be my onClick() function - not updated the state correctly.

Comment: "setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor)"  - is the error your update gives.  Can fix it by adding the .bind(this, 'FileOptions) to handleClick.  However, it still does not load the new set of buttons

Comment: check the new flow of your component

Comment: I simply setState on the raisedButton and no more handleClick

Comment: It was the onClick() function that was causing it not to work by not updating the state properly.  I was able to keep the code pretty much the way I had it by adding in your onClick setState edition.  Thank you for all of the help

Answer (score 0):

If `this.state.selected` is a string containing the component name, then I think this should work:

```
let SelectedComponent = this.state.selected;
return <div>{SelectedComponent ? <SelectedComponent /> : <MainMenu />}</div>;
```

The name of the variable containing the component must be capitalized. For more info see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: Doesn't work.  I tried adding the tags before and it didn't work

Comment: oops I think the variable name needs to be capitalized. sec

Comment: Not a bad idea - still doesn't work though haha. You think this would have an easy solution

Comment: @user3622460 is the content of `this.state.selected` a string containing the component name? also, do you get an error when you try this?

Comment: Yes it is.  I'm not getting an error, it's failing to open FileOptions and if I set selected to MainMenu by default (which in this case I would have to), it doesn't render out the main menu buttons.  You can see that the handleClick() function is suppose to update the state with the name of the button pressed (which is the Component name to be rendered)